# bargraph: Ordering mean and SE to match spreadsheet order

Tags: r, plot

I have made this figure in SigmaPlot but I want to make it R. It is a grouped bar graph with SE bars have 3 groups composed of four sub-groups. I can't get the figure to match the spreadsheet's order:

```
Treatment   Guild   mean    se
Untreated   Ground  0.46    1.1976
Treated Ground  0.79    1.1976
Reference   Ground  0.88    1.1976
Untreated   Cavity  0.87    1.1976
Treated Cavity  0.25    1.1976
Reference   Cavity  1.63    1.1976
Untreated   Canopy  15.13   1.1976
Treated Canopy  9.83    1.1976
Reference   Canopy  23.8    1.1976
Untreated   Shrub   7.79    1.1976
Treated Shrub   4.58    1.1976
Reference   Shrub   5.92    1.1976
```

My code is here:

```
library(sciplot)
data=read.csv

par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#figure3
fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=Treatment,group=Guild, response=mean, data=data,ylim=c(0,30), cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=1.0,
                xlab="Habitat", names.arg=c("Untreated","Treated","Reference"), ylab="Mean abundance of birds/site (±SE)",
                col=c("black","gray","white","gray30")
)
            segments(fig$xvals,data$mean+data$se,fig$xvals,data$mean-data$se)
            segments(fig$xvals-.05,data$mean+data$se,fig$xvals+.05,data$mean+data$se)        #Add the top cap
            segments(fig$xvals-.05,data$mean-data$se,fig$xvals+.05,data$mean-data$se)        #Add the bottom cap

            box(bty="l")
            legend("topleft", bty="n", leg.lab=c("Ground", "Cavity", "Canopy", "Shrub"), col=c("black","gray","white","gray30"))
```

How do I get the mean and SE order to match that of of the data file?

Comment: Duplicate of many, many questions about the plot ordering of factors. Please search for: [r] plot order factor levels

Comment: The default alphabetical ordering in R is what I believe is causing this problem.

Comment: Exactly. Now, please do some searching. The answers on how to modify the ordering are readily available.